# List other og members from the current user group on his profile page

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am new to organic groups,  I ran into a problem, I am a member of some organic group, I need to list other members of same group on my profile page, 
I am working on drupal 7 with Organic group 7.x-2.9

Comment: This requires a small bit of custom code I think. Are you comfortable using a small module to give the gid to the view?

Comment: Yes, I can go with the custom module.